# Nest how pass module in another module with dynamic modules

Tags: nestjs

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-pike-0bhwh?file=/src/handlerModule/handler.module.ts

I read docs about nest dynamic modul, but don't undestand how pass correct.

Comment: Could you specify what you're actually wanting to achieve here? I looked over your code and wrote an answer but I've had to delete that as I feel it may not be relevant.

I need to know: what module is intended to be dynamic? Where are you passing (or wanting) this module? What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Comment: btw, to read more about this topic: https://dev.to/nestjs